# Definition: Extractive Goods (Comtrades HS-Categorization)

Tags: resource-economics, definition

I'm currently writing a paper on China in Africa and I'd like to compare Africas Exports to China with its exports to Europe and the USA. More specifically I'd like to find out if the Exports to China consist of more natural resources than those to Africas other trading partners. However I find it hard to distinguish between "extractive goods" and non-extractive ones. So far I used Comtrades HS-categorization and the categories:

- 5 mineral products
- 9 wood and articles of wood; wood charcoal; cork and articles of cork; manufactures of straw, of esparto or of other plaiting materials; basketware and wickerwork
- 14 natural or cultured pearls, precious or semi-precious stones, precious metals, metals clad with precious metal and articles thereof; imitation jewellery; coin
- 15 base metals and articles of base metal

Do you think this wouldd be ok, or do you have any sources that state which categories to define as "extractive"?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little late, (just joined this forum two hours ago) but if it is still relevant. You should look at the Australian Department of Foreign Affairs and Trade TRIEC system (Google "DFAT TRIEC") It is an established system and useful for high level groupings. You might try to use their groupings and hopefully be able to answer the questions from the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

goods which fall under  below catogery are extractive goods in international trade - volatility in price , non renewable , goods which are unevenly distributed in world.

(Source )
John Helliwell International Journal Vol. 29, No. 4, Economic Interdependence (Autumn, 1974)Published by: Sage Publications

Comment: Do you have a source/reference for your proposed definition?

Comment: I added it to answer amigo